# NodeJs Stream doesn't work in Google Chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, stream, video-streaming

I'm streaming an mp4-file via stream into a html5 videoplayer. It does work on firefox but doesn't on chrome.

Can somebody explain that to me?

Thanks guys

Comment: We cannot help you unless you add more details. Do you have any js errors? Is the issue present only with a single installation of chrome or in every single one? What do you mean with "it doesn't work"?

Comment: There are no errors at all, but I've found the mistake. The webpage gets a wrong status, identifiyng the response as a document, not a media page.

Comment: But thank you very much :D